# Retreive Policies from Apigee X through the Apigee Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

I'm recently moved from Apigee Edge to Apigee X.  In both tools, I'm working with Python3.7 and the Apigee Api to retrieve data.

First of all, I have noticed that there are quite differences between those two Apis. My problem is that I'm struggling with retrieve basic data from the ApigeeX Api.

When I was working with Apigee Edge I used to retrieve the policies using the following Api: https://apidocs.apigee.com/docs/policies/1/routes/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apis/%7Bapi_name%7D/revisions/%7Brevision_number%7D/policies/get

But I'm not able to find that same Api in the ApigeeX Api. Is there any way to retrieve the Policies and its content from an Api proxy or a Shared Flow in ApigeeX using its Api?

If you need anything else, more data or reference please just ask!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For API Proxy - You can use ***[organizations.apis.revisions](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/reference/apis/apigee/rest/v1/organizations.apis.revisions/get)***

For SharedFlow - You can use ***[organizations.sharedflows.revisions](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/reference/apis/apigee/rest/v1/organizations.sharedflows.revisions/get)***